# Does defeating minions reward extra gold?

Tags: slay-the-spire

When fighting an Elite Enemy, they can sometimes summon minions to assist them in the fight. Defeating the Elite causes any surviving minions to run away. Will defeating the minions before defeating the Elite reward me with extra gold after the fight?

Comment: I do not think so. I believe you only get rewarded depending on what kind of encounter it is (normal, elite or boss).

Comment: @mordi2k Can you post this as an answer?

Comment: I can't really confirm it, so I'm not 100% sure its right

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Defeating minion does not award extra gold.
I do not have hard evidence, however:

- If it did, some fights could be exploited to get infinite gold, e.g. Gremlin leader or Reptomancer, which would be a major balance issue.
- Cards that have Fatal effects do not work on minions (Feed, Hand of Greed...), hinting that killing these enemies is irrelevant outside of the fight itself

It makes all sense, because in an encounter with Minions, there are 2 main strategies for winning the fight: Killing minions to control the enemy's damage output, or focusing the elite/boss to kill it as fast as possible. Rewarding Minion kills would favorize decks that are good at killing minions, thus harming the diversity of decks.

[As @Mordi2k said](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/405682/does-defeating-minions-reward-extra-gold/405888#comment569658_405682), gold rewards only depend on the type of fight (and Ascension level I might add) and as it is written [in the game wiki](https://slay-the-spire.fandom.com/wiki/Elites), Elite encounters reward 25-35 gold.

Indirectly related: The 2 birds in the Awakened One fight (Act 3 boss) are not Minions, so Fatal effects work on them, but you can defeat the boss without killing them.
The fight has no gold reward though.